# Could not load file or assembly via AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net

I have got the following code to load DLL to a new `AppDomain` and I am facing the error:

> Could not load file or assembly

Please, any clue what I am missing?

```
const string pluginFolder = "Plugins";
var   _domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup
   {
        ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
        ShadowCopyDirectories = null,
        CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, pluginFolder),
        ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        PrivateBinPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, pluginFolder)
    };


var adi = new AppDomainInitializer(AppDomainInit);
_domainSetup.AppDomainInitializer = adi;

var PersonalDomain = 
    AppDomain.CreateDomain("SomeAppDomainName", null, _domainSetup);

var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\myFile.dll");

var LoadedAssembly = PersonalDomain.Load(assemblyName);
```

Comment: I would try to activate Fusion logging and use the Fusion log viewer to see where it goes wrong. Additionally, use SysInternal's Process Monitor to see where your app searches for the assembly in the file system.

Comment: Does it load fine in main domain with the same code?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, It is. The problem is that I have to implement it  for the personal AppDomains

Comment: Did you try loading it into the current domain ? `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a separate AppDomain for your plugins? AppDomains aren't substitutes for sandboxing.

Comment: @Dai I have to unload them later.

Comment: please have a look at http://mef.codeplex.com/ & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164072.aspx plz check if these are of any help.